# Network interface needs to be manually started

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS 6.3 machine that when rebooting does not bring up its network interface.

I have to manually connect it via the GUI each and every time by choosing 'System eth0':

[image: screenshot]

Please let me know how I can fix this!

Thanks a million,

Dan

Answer (score 7):

Changing line in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

from

```
ONBOOT=no
```

to

```
ONBOOT=yes
```

Fixed this

Answer (score 0):

After I reboot the CentOS 6.4, the network interface is not getting the IP, also when I try to start or restart network service nothing happened.
I used system-config-network tools, and compare the config files, it adds below lines to the end, and after reboot it's OK.

```
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
```

before I have below configurations, but it's not working.

```
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
```

I hope this helps.